# Javascript - Control flow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a little help in best practices around "control flow" within javascript. In the below example my updateUI function is not properly working because my saveData function has not yet completed.

```
function save(data){
   saveData(data);
   updateUI();
}
```

For a temporary fix, I did this

```
function save(data){
if(saveData(data)){
   updateUI();
   }
}
```

Update: Here is my saveData method

```
function saveData(data){

$.ajax({
    url: url, // a variable, not important for this example
    data: data,
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { return true; },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})
```

I feel like I should learn the "standard" way, if such one exists.

Comment: What's saveData doing?  How could updateUI execute if it hasn't completed?  is it doing anything asynchronously?  I don't see why wrapping it in an `if` statement would make a difference.

Comment: Yes, saveData is an ajax call to post some data to a database. I do not want to put my updateUI method within the success handler of the ajax call, as it really doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `saveData` is calling an AJAX function (e.g. `$.ajax`), have it return the result of that AJAX function:

```
function saveData() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url, // a variable, not important for this example
        data: data,
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json"
    }).fail(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

and then use jQuery deferred chaining to update the UI:

```
saveData().done(updateUI).fail(showError);
```

It allows you to avoid ever having to pass callback functions into your `saveData` call, which then allows you to completely separate your data saving logic from your UI logic.

**EDIT**  I've updated the code to show how you can include a default `fail` handler also using deferred objects, but still return the `promise` so that you can handle your UI updating outside.

Comment: Alnitak, this is actually a very elegant solution and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I am indeed using .ajax. I may be a bit lost on how to return properly though. Presently I am getting a boolean "true" being returned.

Comment: @JasonWells what does that boolean signify?  An async method can't normally "return" anything (except a `promise` to return something later...)

Comment: I have a return true within the success handler of the ajax request. E.G, success: function(data){ return true; }, error: function(e){ console.log(e) }

Comment: @JasonWells that `return true` will never be evaluated - async methods don't `return` their values to a caller.  The `.done` method will only be called if the AJAX succeeds.  You can use `.fail` to register an error handler.

Comment: My architecture may be wrong though, so I'd appreciate feedback.

Comment: Alnitak, thanks that's really helpful. What exactly is the point of the success handler within .ajax then? Just in case we want to orchestrate some post success logic within the ajax call itself?

Comment: @JasonWells - the `function(data) { return true; }` is not executed until the AJAX response comes back.  Does `saveData` return anything?

Comment: @JasonWells the `success:` handler is the _old_ (but still supported) way of doing things.  The `.done` way appeared in jQuery 1.5

Comment: I updated my post with my saveData method. Alnitak, so I really shouldn't even be including those handlers?

Comment: @JasonWells there's no need for them, if that's your entire method.  If you wanted to do something "save data related" then your `saveData` function could include an additional `.done` (or `success:`) handler.  Like you said, it's all about separation of concerns.  If your `saveData` has no concerns _other than making the `POST` happen_ then it needs no internal handlers.

Comment: Hmm, getting a saveData() not defined when I try and do.. saveData(data).done(updateUI()); I'm on jQuery 1.7.1 fyi

Comment: Don't put the braces after `updateUI` - you want to pass a function reference, not the result of calling `updateUI()`

Comment: Still no dice, seems to choke anytime I add done().. I even tried saveData(data).done(); and .done(test) - where test was just a function with an alert();

Comment: Actually, should my saveData() method be returning anything at this point? I removed the success handler and consequently the return true;

Comment: @JasonWells see my updated answer - it needs to return the result of `$.ajax()`

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks again, I am a little confused on how to raise an exception within fail?

e.g, fail( $("#error").text("An exception has occured:"));  I want to display the raised exception there.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your saveData is an a-synchronous method. You need to call updateUI() in the oncomplete event.

Have a look at [this article](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/) and read up on [promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Comment: `saveData` doesn't necessarily have an `oncomplete` event, unless they built `saveData` upon a framework that provided that.

Comment: Roblll, thanks. As I described above, I am using .ajax within saveData() and we can certainly put our updateUI call within the success handler of .ajax. However from a separation of concerns standpoint I don't believe saveData should need to know about updating a UI. It should save data, and do that only. As there are cases where I need to call that and updating the UI is not necessary.

Comment: You can implement it as a promise.  Being that there is no reference to jQuery except in the tagging though, I wouldn't want to assume that `oncomplete` is available in their `saveData` function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

You could provide a callback function to the saveData method -- which you would then call when saveData is complete.

```
var saveData = function(data, cb){
    // do something with data to save it
    cb.apply(this, ['arguments', 'as', 'an','array']); // or use .call instead
}
```

You could implement some events, so that your updateUI method listens for an event, which when it occurs it causes updateUI to run, which you fire when you're finished saveData. jQuery provides one, as well as Backbone.

There are a ton of ways to get this done -- choose the one that works best for you.

Comment: Thanks. I am using .ajax within my saveData() method, which does offer a success handler. I just felt like my saveData method should do one thing, and have no concern about updating the UI, since each time I saveData I will not need to reload the UI, only in certain cases. Consequently, I was trying to orchestrate that in the save() method I showed above.

Comment: @JasonWells the current correct approach is to use deferred objects and `.done`, per my answer.

Comment: @JasonWells in that case you can just pass your callback function to the `success` option in the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: @tkone passing callbacks to `$.ajax` is _so_ 2010 ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak sure it is.  But it's also very straight forward and easy to understand.  I've found some people have issues figuring out how `$.deferred` works and how they can chain `.done` to a method call.